# JavaScript gives undefined value from JSON array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, undefined

I am new to JS and I have a problem and can't get the solution. I have written a backend with Java SE, Jersey and Jackson. Everything is fine. My REST endpoint is running. But I cannot figure how to reference that json array object. The "time" values are working correct. The array of "team" say always "undefined".

I want to fill a HTML table with those values. Here is the code snippet:

```
<script>
    var dataExchange = []

    $.ajax({
        method:'GET',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/api/calendar',
        success:function(response){
            dataExchange = response
            buildTable(dataExchange)
            console.log(dataExchange)
        }
    })

    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('eventTable')

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

             var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].dateOfEvent}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].team.teamName}</td> <---Here is the problem
                      </tr>`
             table.innerHTML += row
        }
    }
</script>
```

Thats the JSON from the backend:

```
[{"dateOfEvent":"2019-07-18T18:30","team":[{"teamName":"Salzburg"}]},{"dateOfEvent":"2019-07-18T18:30","team":[{"teamName":"Sturm"}]},{"dateOfEvent":"2019-10-23T09:45","team":[{"teamName":"Capitols"}]},{"dateOfEvent":"2019-10-23T09:45","team":[{"teamName":"KAC"}]}]
```

Please, can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here and how does this exactly work with JavaScript?

Comment: Are you parsing `data` before using it in the function?

Comment: What does the `console.log(dataExchange)` output in the console? A string or an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[i].team` is not an object - it is an *array* with one object. You need to use `data[i].team[0].teamName`:

```
function buildTable(data) {
  var table = document.getElementById('eventTable');

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = `<tr>
                 <td>${data[i].dateOfEvent}</td>
                 <td>${data[i].team[0].teamName}</td>
               </tr>`
    table.innerHTML += row;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `json` it has to be something like this:

```
<td>${data[i].team[0].teamName}</td>
```